# How to make jQuery replace element style even after reloading

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make jquery replace element style in a way even after reloading it remains the same. This is what I have so far

```
$("#myId").css("background","#000");
```

This only override the style temporarily once I reload the page everything goes back to normal.

Comment: And why jQuery at all for this? Just add a rule in your CSS

Comment: Use `sessionStorage`.

Comment: You need to use a datastore to retain the state of the page, as it will be cleared on each new request. To do this you could use `localStorage`, `sessionStorage`, a cookie, a server-side database... Any of the above.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thanks alot, I thought of all this, I just thought maybe someone knows better and could shed some light. Thanks again.

Comment: Do you happen to have some css elsewhere that would override your jQuery code with `!important`?

Comment: @MattCremeens not at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Straightforward solution seems to be adding a simple rule in your css. Obviously, you will get that applied always, even after reload.

But I think you need to change color on some event and then want to store that color for next page reload. You can use `sessionStorage` to store the selected color. Then you can check on every page reload, whether there is any value already set for that in `sessionStorage` and if there is, you can simply apply that color value on your div.

```js
var colors = ["red", "green", "blue"];

function setColor( color )
{
  $("#demo").css("background-color", color);
  sessionStorage.setItem("lastcolor", color);
}

var lastColor = sessionStorage.getItem("lastcolor");
if( lastColor !== undefined )
  setColor( lastColor );

$("#change-color").on("click", function(e){
  var color = colors[ Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length) ];
  setColor( color );
});//
```

```css
#demo
{
  border: thick solid red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
</div>

<button id="change-color">Change</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot,
Javascript is a client-side langage. It will run the same code every time you will reload the page.

Comment: Yes, it runs the same code every time. But to save state you can now use `localStorage` and `sessionStorage` much like cookies.

Comment: indeed, but the question is about JQuery.

Comment: You can use `localStorage` in jQuery too.